# using xscale and yscale within subplots of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create subplots like

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
```

and I plot with

```
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, y)
```

now I would like to format the axis as

```
ax1.xscale('log')
ax1.yscale('log')
```

but this leads to

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'yscale'
```

How do I format the axis for the two subplot?

Comment: Instead do `ax1.set_xscale('log')`